# Record mono from stereo input

Tags: winapi, audio, winmm

I have an audio interface with two inputs: microphone and instrument. In Windows it is represented by a single stereo audio input, left channel gets microphone input and right channel gets instrument input.

I open recording session like this:

```
void CALLBACK waveIn(HWAVEIN hwi, UINT uMsg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2);

// ...

const int nchannels = 2;
const int sr = 48000;

HWAVEIN hwi;
WAVEFORMATEX wfe = 
{
    WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT,         // wFormatTag
    nchannels,                      // nChannels
    sr,                             // nSamplesPerSec
    sr * sizeof(float) * nchannels, // nAvgBytesPerSec
    sizeof(float) * nchannels,      // nBlockAlign
    32,                             // wBitsPerSample
    0                               // cbSize
};
MMRESULT openResult = waveInOpen(&hwi, 0, &wfe, (DWORD_PTR)waveIn, 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
// ..set up buffers..
MMRESULT startResult = waveInStart(hwi);
```

Then process samples in `waveIn` function. It works fine, but I only need to work with instrument (right channel) data and not interested in microphone. I tried setting `nchannels=1` in the code above, hoping it would mix both channels, but instead I only get data from microphone (left) channel. Is there a way to set up recording from a stereo input to get only right (or mix of both) audio channel data (as mono recording)?

Comment: You just do the required processing in your `waveIn` callback function. At `sampleRate` number of times a second, you get `nchannels` samples. Either select the one you want and then pass it on to further processing, or mix them together and pass on the result to further processing. Simply discard one channel or the other, or add them both together - it's straight forward.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't alter the actual processing code, it expects mono input, and I don't have sources for it.

Comment: I've been thinking more about this over the months - what's stopping you from writing the `waveIn` (shown above) callback function? In it, you could strip/mix the channels as needed, before calling the original processing function from yours? As far as the 3rd party code would know, it was simply called by the MM sub-system with a single channel of data.

Comment: The code above is essentially a result of reverse engineering of a compiled binary (i.e. not an actual code and nothing to compile) that I hoped to patch slightly to make it work with my hardware properly.

Comment: @nOrd - Ahhhhh! I see. Hmm - haven't done any serious reverse-engineering/hacking for close to a decade now. Well, short of finding a code-cave and re-directing the program-flow to it and some new code of your own, before calling the original code, you might need to attempt the mission via Api Hooking (i.e the Detours library or an equivalent). I'd be happy to have a play with the program with either/both OllyDbg and IDA Pro Advanced if you like, but haven't messed with a program in a similar manner in ages. You might get better answers from the exetools or tuts4you forums. ;)